# AutoCompleteTextView always keeps focus

Tags: android, user-interface, focus

I have `2 AutoCompleteTextViews` in an activity (LinearLayout) and several `additional controls` (radiogroups, buttons, etc). Somehow the AutoCompleteTextViews are `never losing focus`.

As Example:
The user clicks on an AutoCompleteTextView, the control gets the focus. So the cursor starts blinking, the autocomplete dropdown list and the keyboard is shown. This is fine. 
However if the `user now clicks on of the radio buttons` (or another control), the cursor in the AutoCompleteTextView `is still blinking` and the keyboard is still shown.

How to make the focus disappear automatically?

**EDIT:** xml code

```
                <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/ediFrom"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="" />
```

Comment: Show us some XML code of the corresponding AutoComplete

Comment: Hello, i added the xml code above

Answer (score 8):

Only solution that worked for me is to add this line

```
android:focusable="true" 
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

To parent of AutoCompleteTextView (like LinearLayout etc..)

Comment: This solution works not on all devices. Solution from @hidro is more universal. But maybe there is need to combine theese two solutions, I did not check this.

Answer (score 3):

In order to avoid setting everything else `focusable` (which is painful if you happen to use the same text view in many other layouts), we opt to override the logic to intercept touch screen events at activity level instead:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    View v = getCurrentFocus();
    if (v instanceof EditText) {
        int scrcoords[] = new int[2];
        v.getLocationOnScreen(scrcoords);
        // calculate the relative position of the clicking position against the position of the view
        float x = event.getRawX() - scrcoords[0];
        float y = event.getRawY() - scrcoords[1];

        // check whether action is up and the clicking position is outside of the view
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
                && (x < 0 || x > v.getRight() - v.getLeft()
                || y < 0 || y > v.getBottom() - v.getTop())) {
            if (v.getOnFocusChangeListener() != null) {
                v.getOnFocusChangeListener().onFocusChange(v, false);
            }
        }
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
}
```

If you put this logic in your base activity, any screen with an edit text now will fire `onFocusChange` when you tap anywhere outside it. By listening to `onFocusChange` you can `clearFocus` or `requestFocus` on another view. It's a hack more or less but at least you don't have to set focusable for any other items on many layouts.

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)

Comment: Your solution in combination with @Michal Heneš' s answer helped me to resolve my issue. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

have u tried with `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` for `each view`
code snippet

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
      android:id="@+id/ediFrom"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:singleLine="true"
      android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
      android:text="" />
```

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2008/12/touch-mode.html

Comment: No, unfortunately this doesn't change anything.

Comment: see @Michal Heneš [anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21941328/2445763)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `setOnDismissListener()` to clear the focus whenever the dropdown is dismissed (value picked, clicked outside)

This Kotlin code works fine for me, you can easily rewrite it to java too:

```kotlin
materialAutoCompleteTextBox.setOnDismissListener {
  materialAutoCompleteTextBox.clearFocus()
}
```