# How to lose focus from auto complete text view and gain when focus when user tap on it in android?

Tags: android, performance, textview

I am developing an application with auto-complete text-view. My very first page contains auto-complete text-view which is working as SEARCH field. The moment my application launches, keyboard is also displaying and which hides my other contents in my first page.

I am sure that this will make user to feel bad. I need to overcome this. I need to lose focus of auto-complete text view initially and when user tap on it, keyboard should appear.

This is the listener code of my autocomplete text view.

```
 AutoCompleteTextView jsearch;
 jsearch = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.asearch);
 jsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            String newText = s.toString();
            if(validNet()) {
                new getJsonCategory().execute(newText);
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }  else alertBox();

        }
    });
```

Comment: Try [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495225/how-to-disable-autocompletetextviews-drop-down-from-showing-up) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21939657/autocompletetextview-always-keeps-focus)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways you can do.

Step 1:on launching the activity you can stop the popup of key board by the following code paste after oncreate:

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

Step 2:

```
In code make Autocompletetextview .setFocusable(false);
```

Let me know is it use full or on.so that i can help you more

Comment: Wow... Thank you a lot. Step 1 works perfectly. Step 2 didnt. Anyway, thank you.